# Automatic Login from one website to another

Tags: javascript, autologin

I have a website A and when I click a button on website A I have to redirect to a page on website B.

In order to access website B I open a new window with the url.

```
var url = 'http://mywebsite';

window.open(url, '_blank');
```

This works to open the window with the website Bs page however it directs the user to the login page and if the users logs in from there he is redirected to website Bs home page. I want the redirection to be to a specific page not to the home page.

I tried adding the credentials to the url as so:

var url = 'http://mywebsite';

```
window.open(Http://username:password@url, '_blank'); ( not exact syntax )
```

However the user is still redirected to the login page where the details have to be entered.

Please note that the credentials are the same for both websites. I have not yet found any other methods to try out.

Comment: Do you own those websites ? If so, maybe you can do something like passing a token from one website to another, otherwise your user will have to be logged in before, or it's not possible IMO.

Comment: Yes I own both of them, however this process has to be for any user that logs on to the system. In order to pass a token wouldn't you have to be logged into both websites though?

Comment: I was thinking of a cryptographic token containing login information that would be sent from A to B, I can't think of anything else.